# Is there any tag or element in HTML to do somthing like the following image:

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dom, bootstrap-4, frontend

[image]

I need to make something like this container which has a border and centered caption.

Comment: The [forms element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Forms) would be a good place to start looking. This question shows no research effort so far, and is likely to be downvoted.

Comment: thanks for downvoted, but already I used <fieldset> element but it appears without border.

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS as part of the question to show that effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) and [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) elements.

```css
legend {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Comment</legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add your comment"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy but the border doesn't appear.

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS as part of the question. It's impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't centre the legend in Firefox. If you use  `margin:0 auto;` instead of `text-align: center;`, it'll centre in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Alohci. I've edited to make that improvement.